# Why do economists say that growth is necessary?

Tags: philosophy-of-economics

Now I could ask this question on the economics site but I'm afraid it would be closed shortly after. Who dares to question one of its basic principles. As if it's a Natural law. But why should it be like that? To me economic growth is not a sign of progress.

On the contrary. It's a sign of regression insofar Nature is concerned.

I can imagine an economy where there is no growth. Production is constant in that case. Still economical principles will apply. Supply and demand doesn't demand growth.

Then why do they say that economy needs growth?

Question update: I just saw on TV that the number of people suffering from hunger has risen with 20 000 000. How is this possible if there are people owing owing the capital of a small county? The difficulty with everybody being able to be a millionair is that not everybody *can* be one. I dont have a problem with being a millionair. If someone wants to be one, why not (it is not that good for Nature but that's another issue). But what *drives* someone to get more and more? Why should capital grow? Should you let it grow if the capital of others is diving below the minimal of that necessary for existence? Or even below it due to debts? Of course if the debt or having no money (when one wants to use money for living instead of being independent of it which is almost impossible and even forbidden) is due to your own fault but in many times  it  isn't. Why the ideal of growth? I was always taught at school everybody should get the same. Then later on you are told that you have to increase your capital (which doesn't necessarily mean that everybody *doesn't get the same but in practice it turns out this way).

So, my question is not about if growth gives a growth of standards of living (these differ from one culture to another), but rather why it is presupposed that growth is needed in economy. Regardless of standards of life increasing. What is the philosophy behind this aspect of economy?

Comment: As you say, this is the "mainstream view", but there are alternative views regarding. See [Sustainability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sustainability)

Comment: This is a question on neoclassical economics, not on philosophy. There are other theories out there. And what you suggest effectively means nobody had an incentive to invest, which would mean a degeneration of the economy and means of production. Additionally rising numbers of unemployment, no possibility to build or buy a home, and things becoming more and more expensive. Good perspectives for sure!

Comment: You can see also [Thomas Piketty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Piketty)'s [successful books](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_in_the_Twenty-First_Century)

Comment: John Stuart Mill anticipates with equanimity 'the stationary state' of the economy in Principles of Political Economy, 1848, 7th ed. 1870, Bk IV, ch.4.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking iI am just curious about the philosophy behind mainstream economics. I cant ask this on the economics site because that shakes its very foundation.

Comment: This is a view of bourgeois economists.

Comment: I'm not sure how much of a philosophical explanation this provides, but here's an idea: human nature makes it so we want to improve things all the time, this naturally leads to better technology, to getting more out of natural resources, increased productivity, etc. So even if you didn't make an attempt to maximize profit, etc., I think you'd still have innovation in many ways. It's not clear to me how you could stop that from leading to increased growth.

Comment: Because, being economists, they mostly focus on the economic indicators of well-being. It is the same sort of tunnel vision that Maslow called [the law of the instrument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_instrument):"*it is tempting, if the only tool you have is a hammer, to treat everything as if it were a nail*". See [The Limits to Growth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Limits_to_Growth#Positive_reviews) and [Spence's questioning](https://www.theatlantic.com/business/archive/2016/11/economic-growth/506423/) of the underlying premise for alternative views.

Comment: [Center for the Advancement of the Steady State Economy](https://steadystate.org)

Comment: This is a technical question. Macroeconomics is a complex interplay of money, price, demand, supply and more, and "growth" is a technical term in economics. To better understand your own question, you should consult a macroeconomics textbook.

Comment: @FoxMulderEven if technology progresses then growth is not nessecary. The new can teplace the old like in evolution.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking It depends what you call a good perspective. Everybody in the world could have a home if the rich (a small group in possesion of half the value of all goods on Earth) decide to share their property. But their relentless need to let their property grow arrests this wanting to share. Its more more and more. And the future will be even grimmer. All money flows in their direction to fulfill their need to grow. Why are they so keen about this? What about the Natural world? Do they even care about that? Isnt relentless growth a threat to Nature? We cant live without Nature.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking People in so-called primitive societies live a fulfilling life without producing more and more.

Comment: Economics/politics question. Adding a tag "philosophy of [insert whatever topic here]" is not a way to make any and all question a fit for this site...

Comment: @armand Of course it is a philosophical question. Thats what the philosphy of economics tag is for. Asking this on the site you recommand leads to immediate closure of the question. I have asked it before there. Try it... There is no tag for the philosophy of whatever.

Comment: Maybe there's a reason you successively get banned from every single stack exchange site...

Comment: @armand Indeed! Thats why Im asking my questions here...They think Im too much thinking for myself...

Comment: This isn't thinking. This is dreaming, and totally ignorant of human psychology, politics, and economic theory. There is no bliss in a supposed "state of nature". It is hard work. Every day. Sustaining no more than about 100 million humans world-wide at best. So if you like to let 99% of the population die in agony and the rest live a miserable life because politics are corrupt, fine. But the latter is the only problem we have.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking If all the superrich ( and they are because of the ideal of growth) would give away half they owe there would be no hunger.

Comment: But the principle of growth has nothing to do with wealth distribution, taxation systems, and regulatory policy. Chicago School of Friedman et. al. (neoliberalism) tried to develop an economical reasoning behind wealth concentration around 1970 and that's what, for example, the Trump administration and most conservative governments still sell as "economy-friendly" gospel, but this school of thought has been shown not to be empirically valid, which every critical economist will be able to tell you. That's why I keep on telling you that this is neither philosophy nor how economic theory works.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking I think economy wouldnt be economy anymore without the priciple of growth. This is inherent in economics. It is a dreamlike quality (to use your words) which doesnt means it doesnt pay attention to reality. Maybe one day the economists wake up.

Comment: The principle of growth is a necessity for any investment, research, or development taking place and even necessary to keep the current level of production. It is a scientific principle not up to discussion and just describes how economy works. It is impartial as to how wealth is distributed or whether we invest in a sustainable or destructive economy. The latter is a matter of policy and ethics, not of economics. It is normative individual and political decisions which make the bad things you describe happen, not economic growth. Maybe one day you understand this crucial difference.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking I hope I never understand...

Answer (score 3):

economies must grow to furnish the growing needs of a growing population. A stagnant economy chained to a growing population means poverty, or extreme income disparity, or both.

Comment: Hi Niels, as far as I know, the world currently supplies more than enough food and resources to provide for more population than it currently has. Assuming better redistribution, why should low growth / lack of growth necessarily lead to increased poverty or income disparity?

Comment: @Fox Mulder, at some point you’d think an exponentially growing population would outpace a stagnant economy because there’s more mouths to feed. As population grows, distribution needs to grow as well. More people born creates demand for more things than just food: health care, shelter, water, etc

Comment: @CottonHeadedNinnymuggins FoxMulder is right. There is so much produced to feed or shelter everyone. That is, the money corresponding to the produced goods is more than enough to feed and shelter everyone. This money though goes to the ones already having more than enough because they want even more. But why do they want more and more? What is that? Power? Compensation? Just pleasure from the products produced? Why is growth considered more important than the state of Nature?

Comment: Deschele, the fact that a lot of money goes to the rich is a different concept. Ask Jeff Bezos what his drive is for more $$$ because I sure don’t know (he’s got enough $$$ for retirement for many, ***MANY*** generations). Growth often leads to increases in GDP per capita which is a major indicator of standard of living, which is why it often has a place above nature.

Answer (score 2):

A growing economy is *required* to support a growing population. As population increases, demand for many things (especially necessities: food, water, shelter, etc) increases.

You might be tempted to say “so what if demand increases, we don’t *need* to supply gamers with Xbox’s,... we don’t *need* to supply people with fast cars.” Except **people tend to strive for things that are in their best interest** which means these gamers and speed demons are going try to get what they want.

One way to get those things is to buy those things. If nobody is making them, those gamers and speed demons *will be willing to pay someone top dollar to make those things for them* because it’s a heck of a lot of time and work to do it themself. When they’re willing to pay top dollar, some young entrepreneur might realize this opportunity: they can start making Xbox’s and fast cars and sell them for a lot of money.

You see, since people work in their self-interest, this keeps demand for (even unneeded items) on the rise. When people want something, they’ll try to get it, and if they want it bad enough, they’ll put in the time, money, and effort to get it. The more people that are born (which is a current trend), the more demand increases for MANY things, and therefore the more incentive for people to supply these things to people. As there’s more goods and services supplied, the economy grows, so it’s ***NECESSARY*** that the economy should grow as population increases.

**TL;DR**: As population increases, so does demand because humans need (and want) many things. These needs and wants are met by suppliers who see opportunity to make money, this makes the economy larger. This growth is needed to maintain or improve the current standard of living that some people may or may not enjoy.

Comment: Does the population always have to grow?

Comment: @Halsey the original question is “Why do economists say that growth is necessary”—did I not answer that? Let’s say population stops growing... the drive for people to do what’s in their best interest is still there, so innovation and constant seeking for the next best thing still happens (raising demand for other things, possibly lowering it for other goods/services). As humans invent, innovate, and make things more efficient, the quality and quantity of goods and services (in general) rises, also bringing up the standard of living and changing demand. As long as population rises...

Comment: ... The economy should grow in order to keep (or improve) the standard of living

Comment: But the production griws faster than the population. On top of that, most of the result of the griwth (money( goes to the ones already having much. Not to the people of this growing population. Because of the very fact that they want to grow and to have more and more and more. Even the lmore must grow. But why?

Comment: @CottonHeadedNinnymuggins It depends completely what your standards are. Why should the standard be to have more and more? Why should you want the most expensive and in the future even more expensive? Emptiness inside oneself?

Comment: If the population is constant then your answer implies that no growth is necessary.

Comment: The need to want more is already taught to us when young. There is no narural need forpeople to just want more. Its not inherently human. Its demanded by society. I was always told that everybody should get the same. Then later in life the idea is planted to always long for more (in the material sense). But why is this so important? You can say that is Natural by I dont buy that. That means it is no good not to want that.

Comment: As the Solow model can tell you, growth of population is but one way to achieve long-term growth. Production efficiency is another one. The former is no necessity at all, like looking at any G7 country will tell you.

Comment: Population has risen by a factor ten over the last 200 years. Production hss risen by a factor 100 at least. The face of the Earth has even changed significantly in the last 100 years.

Comment: You seem to be telling me why increases production is bad, rather than unnecessary (which was your original question). Increased production itself isn’t a bad thing, innovation is the heart of growth in the world. If population continues rising, production should in order to keep the current standard of living (or improve it). GDP per capita is *usually* a good indicator of standard of living... imagine population rises but production (and GDP) stays the same, GDP per capita lowers, along with the standard of living. For your next comment, different people have different motives...

Comment: ... some people want money because it’s easily used for the sake of something else (usually material/unnecessary items). Other people want love, or power, or a meaningful career that betters the world’s people. Some people want more and more because that’s just how they’re driven. Your next comment: in a sense, yes, a stagnant population implies no necessary growth, but you have to grow in order to *increase the standard of living*. At the same time too, it’s hard to keep demand equal for everything—someone will want the fastest car (or whatever), and suddenly production is allocated different

Comment: ... when production is allocated differently, it’s hard to tell exactly whether the total economy has progressed, but in theory, it may be possible to keep everyone (or almost everyone) satisfied with level production and consumption... but again, it’s hard to tell the economy what to do since motives change, and stuff happens (like recession, etc). Your next comment: psychologically, I think people do simply want *more*, and if they don’t, they want something *different* because they’re bored. Of course there’s plenty of people that are fine with their current lifestyle, no change needed...

Answer (score 1):

Prior to the industrial revolution, it wasn't common that economies would grow in the medium term.  Generally the size of the economy would be based off the resource base you had (farm land, functioning mines).  Adding more people wouldn't produce that many more resources, so as population grew wealth per person plummeted.

Any wealth one person had was an equal amount of wealth another did not.  The economy was a zero-sum game for the most part.

Governments would engage in wars, or build plague-filled cities, to kill the excess population; and if you didn't, plague and famine would come anyway and kill the excess.

Some areas where a bit wealthier, others a bit poorer, based on recent war results and local resources and the like.

The industrial revolution, starting in the Netherlands.  For almost a century the area got slowly wealthier faster than it gained in population.  Then England (and later the rest of Britain) followed suit.

Canals, steam engines, coal, wind and rails caused constant regular economic growth.  Manufacturing and excess wealth caused cities to be a less crappy option, and manufacturing (textiles, ships, etc) started growing economically compared to agriculture.

The power of exponential growth means that a nation that grows 1% per year faster than its rivals, after 100 years is 2.7 times more powerful.  After 200 years it is 7 times more powerful.  After 300 years it is 20 times more powerful.

And the industrial revolution, while it started off at a sustained pace of 1% or so per year, accelerated instead.  In the 1700s it was 1% per capita growth, then by the 1800s it hit 2% per capita growth.  And a population boom also occurred.

In 1600, the UK was a backwater island of a backwater continent.  By 1900, a mere 300 years later, the UK was a world-spanning superpower.  It did this on the heels of 1% to 2% per-capita growth per year.

The modern study of economics comes out of Europe, and the countries of Europe either mimiced the industrial revolution or became conquered provinces of nations that did.  It did not go well for nations that didn't manage this year on year growth.

So economics understands how economies expand, and describes disasters when they don't, because the science of economics was built in a nation that did exactly that (grew), and observed exactly that (lack of growth destroyed countries).

---

The idea that "not everyone can be a millionaire" is a bit vague.

Do you mean "not everyone can be richer than everyone else", where we use "millionaire" to mean relatively rich?  That is true under any universal exchange rate.

If you mean "not everyone can be as rich in resources as a person in the west is that is currently worth a million US dollars", then that may or may not be true.

Suppose the sustained growth in the UK between 1700 and 2000 was about 2.5% per capita per year, and 1.025^300 is about 1600x.  If we start with the average person being "worth" the equivalent of 100$ and earning about 1$ in current dollars per day (about 400$ per year), at the end of 300 years of 2.5% growth the average person is worth 160,000$ and earns 64000$ per year.  (Note that the growth rate I wrote is a bit high; it was closer to 2%)

Do that for another 100 years and it becomes a worth of 1.9 million and earning 750,000$ per year.

You may wonder how that could be plausible.

A situation where batteries and solar power are 1000x cheaper than they are today is far from certain, but far from impossible.  In that scenario, green house gas emissions are no longer a serious problem; instead, we run into net heat flux limits, where the power we use generates heat directly, and radiating that into space is the limit we have.

Before we hit that limit, we'd end up with a society where a good chunk of the planet is wrapped in solar panels (say, 10%) at high efficiency (say 30%), converting 3% of incoming sunlight into useful power.

Using the [Kardashev scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kardashev_scale), 2018 is about 0.73.  A civilization that harnesses 3% of incoming light from the Sun is 0.85 on the scale, 16x "richer" in useful power than our current society.

Even ignoring the idea of using power more efficiently to produce wealth than we do right now, there is room to hit 2.5% annual growth over 100 years with a 16x multiplier.

The worlds current average GDP at PPP is 18k$/year.  Times 16 is 288k$/year; and someone consuming 288k$/year is a decent approximation of a "millionaire" lifestyle.

And if all of the power comes from carbon-free solar and similar (even planes use batteries; batteries are chemical fuel cells that can be easily "recycled" with electricity), it is possible (but difficult) that the ecological impact won't be much off modern day society.

The world is pulling off 2%-3% annual growth rate on a 1% growth in population; so closer to 1%-2% GDP per capital growth rate than the above 2.5%.  To hit 16x wealthier per person, you'd need 186 years of 1.5% per capita growth.

That end state -- where most everyone on the planet lives at the wealth scales of a modern western millionaire -- is very difficult, but not completely implausible.

One of the reasons it isn't implausible is that the industrialized world already did it.  Via economic growth, they "turned everyone into millionaires".

They took the age-old truth that almost everyone lives at the edge of starvation -- the truth of 1600 AD -- and made everyone on average 100x of times richer.  By many measures, the average person in an industrialized or post-industrial country lives at a standard of living exceeding the richest 0.1% of people in 1600 AD.

And the same thing is happening in many parts of the world.  There are areas going from starvation level poverty being the norm to it being an extreme exception in a matter of generations.

There remains the real, difficult problems of not destroying the planet while doing this.

But that is why economics talks about growth, and considers it highly valuable, and not growing to be avoided.  Societies that grew developed the science of modern economics, and the results on the well being of the members of society are huge.

Comment: If well being has increased is the question. There are people even commiting suicide because of money (or not having it). What about the contrast between the super rich and the poor? On top of that there are societies (the so-called primitive ones where primitive is precisely defined as them having not the materials and goods and worldview we have) pepole can lead a rich and fulfilling life.

Comment: @DescheleSchilder Yes, people commit suicide.  And there is wealth contrast.  I'm not sure what that has to do with growth?  Ancient Egypt had near zero growth per capita, and it has a huge contrast between rich and poor.  Non-state societies are very full of murder: https://ourworldindata.org/ethnographic-and-archaeological-evidence-on-violent-deaths - but that is going pretty far off topic.  I didn't state or claim that economic growth was good, I answered "why economics talks about economic growth like it does", which is what you asked.  I also addressed the "not everyone can be" directly.

Comment: Your answer is great. But it is descriptive and not declaring. I still see not why it is so important to economists. Because the whole subject matter would stop to exist maybe. All math formulae would not be valid anymore. I didnt say that a stationary economy does imply equal money distribution. People just dont grow richer and others dint grow poorer. There is no way to avoid some being rich and others having less. It depends what you want. Why wanna have more and more ( as is taught by means of the growth principle)?

Comment: By primitive societied without a state. I mean societies the members of which do not know the very concept of state and growth of economy. There is no money-based murder or criminality in general. How could there be if no money is there. They dont know about the weaponary and technology to protect capital and to produce more and mire. Nevertheless they exist though less and less and the scientific technological and economic way takes over. By words or by plain violence with tech based armory.

Comment: @DescheleSchilder Archeological examining of dead bodies in non-state societies shows high murder rates, generally higher than state societies.  I provided a link.  I am, again, simply answering why economics talks about growth.  Even if a non-state societies where heaven on earth, it wouldn't matter to why economists talk about growth and consider it important.  Economists talk about growth because economics was invented in societies conquering the world with growth, and making the lives of their citizens crazily better while doing so.

Comment: I mean societies as they exist now. If they still have the possibility to exist. I can give you recent examples of state induced murder... The direct cause was economics. Everybody was a billionair in the WeimarRepublic... But it was worth nothing and it led to ww2.

Comment: @DescheleSchilder You seem to have problems focusing on the questions you ask, and are using pretty stupid or incoherent meanings of "billionaire" and "millionaire".  If you say the Weimar Republic was full of billionaires, then easily everyone can be a millionaire.  If not everyone can be a millionaire, then the Weimar Republic was not full of billionaires, for any coherent definition of the two.  I would advise going and taking some basic high school level rhetoric and logic classes before continuing along this discussion.  You are blathering.

Comment: @DescheleSchilder Some mighty big equivocation going on there.

Comment: @Yakk Me blathering is the biggest compliment I can get! Thanks! Everyone was a billionair in Weimar. So everybody was a millionair too. The GM had no value though. I am talking about everyone being a millionair in the sense that the money is worth something. Just blathering about the meaning of a billionaire doesnt contribute anything to the answer. If there is anyone talking logicalky then it is you. And the philosophy of logic is precisely something that cant be applied here. Sorry for you...

Comment: @GArthurBrown Yakk is a logical...

Comment: @DescheleSchilder You are confusing two different meanings of millionaire/billionaire. On one hand, people with millions of dollars are millionaires. On the other hand, if those dollars are worth anything, they don't have the wealth that millionaire connotes. You don't seem to be taking into account how currency works or that wealth is not a fixed quantity.

Comment: @GArturBrown What has to be taken into consideration? People in the Weimar were billionaires. There are notes of 100 000 000 000 DM...I am talking about millionairs or bilonaires who can actually buy everything with these billions. A very small percentage of all people have this status though and they have even thoudands of millions while others dont have anything to eat. Thanks to the view of the inevitability of growth. A logical discussion on the meaning of billionair is just blathering in this context. Everybody knows what I mean with being a millionair.

Comment: @GArthurBrown I mentioned it because not every millionair is a millionair. It depends on what you can get with your millions. All Italians were milionair in the nineties. But they couldnt buy a Masserati.

Comment: @DescheleSchilder If that is your point, you need update date your question to more clearly reflect that.

Comment: *Economists talk about growth because economics was invented in societies conquering the world with growth, and making the lives of their citizens crazily better while doing so* better lives? That depends on your view of better. Its very true though that it conquered the world. Not by reason but by brute force. "The only right way is the way of growth and the way of science" ANATEMA SIT. Luckily there are still reasinable people who dont trust on logic only. Still the question is "Why growth is so important" Your answer just restates the importance of growth. With biased examples, logically...

Comment: @GArthurBrown It is irrelevant to the question. I assume people to be intelligent enough to know what I mean by a millionaire.

Comment: @But you've just used the term in two different senses, ostensibly in support of the same argument. [The Equivocation Fallacy](https://www.txstate.edu/philosophy/resources/fallacy-definitions/Equivocation.html)

Comment: @GArthurBrown There is no argument I want to support. Which argument do you mean?

Comment: @GArthurBrown If you mean that not everyone can be a millionaire, I assumed everybody knew what I mean. Note that it was me who brought up the question about the interpretation of a billionaire. It was our logical friend Yakk who said that I conflated the two. But I was mereky using them equivalently.